# ActiveMQ - Removing queues programmatically

Tags: persistence, queue, activemq-classic

Fellow StackOverflowers, is there a way for me to remove a queue or a topic in ActiveMQ programmatically? I am using ActiveMQ's standard persistency, and my application requires that, on startup, all new queues be dynamically re-created (unless there are messages stored in the queue, in which case, the queue should remain to exist).

I am also creating all queues programmatically through sessions. Is there an equivalent to that procedure, only to delete a queue? Querying and iterating through the existing queues would also be useful, but i haven't found a way to do that yet.

Comment: Were you running ActiveMQ embedded or standalone?

Answer (score 6):

You can also [Delete Destinations](http://activemq.apache.org/delete-inactive-destinations.html) that are inactive for some period of time. Available since Active MQ 5.4

Alternatively if you are running ActiveMQ embedded you can use the API to remove destinations: [Region.removeDestination](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.5.0/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/Region.html#removeDestination%28org.apache.activemq.broker.ConnectionContext,%20org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination,%20long%29)

Answer (score 4):

To remove a destination from ActiveMQ programmatically, you will need to do so via JMX using the `removeTopic` and `removeQueue` methods on the broker MBean (`org.apache.activemq:BrokerName=localhost,Type=Broker`). I have posted some example code to demonstrate this, including the use of the `removeTopic` method, over on Gist:

http://gist.github.com/439668

Hope that helps.

Bruce

Answer (score 2):

If you use spring JmsTemplate, you can do it this way:

```
Connection cn = getJmsTemplate().getConnectionFactory().createConnection();
ActiveMQDestination destination = ActiveMQDestination.createDestination(queueName, ActiveMQDestination.QUEUE_TYPE);             

if(cn instanceof PooledConnection){
    ((PooledConnection)cn).getConnection().destroyDestination(destination );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there's not a lot of concrete examples, there's some documentation about it here :
http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-purge-a-queue.html

Comment: Thanks nos, i'll take a look at the BrokerViewMBean interface later on and see what i can do with it. I'll let you know if it works.