# How can i delete destination from activemq

Tags: activemq-classic

How can i delete a queue from activemq using java.Can any one provide any samples regarding this.I have googled it but i didn't find the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

This SO Thread, and particulary BOdays answer:
[ActiveMQ delete queue from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062677/activemq-delete-queue-from-java)

Points to this blog post by the same author:
http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html

which shows how to this using JMX/Java.

Enjoy